# Java webclient client response memory issue

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, webclient

There is a database, which has 2 unique keys. There is an API hosted to see the values of the database, let say DB of books, which has a book id and another unique id. The API takes the unique id and returns the full information of the book in JSON format. This info is very large. And I want to create a mapper program, which can convert a unique id into a book id with the help of this API.
I am creating a web client with

```
webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(host).defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader("Authorization", apiAuth).defaultHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                .build();
```

The book detail needed is to be included in the host uri e.g. `https://example.com/book?uniqueCode=I03909&size=1` and multiple records can be achieved by giving multiple uniqueCodes with comma between and giving size value.

I am making a get request by:

```
    String response = webClient.get().uri(
            uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/books/")
                    .queryParam("ucodes", ucodes)
                    .queryParam("size", ucodesList.size())
                    .build())
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

I am giving comma seperated ucodes and size from here. And then i get a json string which has list of books, each books a lot of fields including book id, author, year of publishing etc are there. But the problem is i want only the book id data, but a lot of data is comming, so the buffer is getting full, and exception is coming. Is there any way to filter and get only the required data and prevent this buffer full exception.

The response is like:

```
{
"books":[
{
"ucode":"reer2121"
"bookId":"22"
"author":.........
......
......
......

}
]
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:101)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http....
```

Comment: which buffer ? what exception ? valid answers will include a wide variety of topics from creating a dedicated object to fetch the ids only up to pagination of the results.

Comment: @spi updated the exception in question, please check

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23961 maybe the answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to filter you needs if the API is modelated in that way.

You can increase the DataBufferLimit

```
webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(host).defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                        .codecs(configurer -> configurer
                                .defaultCodecs()
                                .maxInMemorySize(10 * 1024 * 1024)) // 10 MB
                        .build())
                .defaultHeader("Authorization", apiAuth).defaultHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                .build();
```

It is increased to handle 10 MB, you can add more if needed.